# Mobius transformation and Group action

Tags: group-actions, mobius-transformation

Let $G$ be $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$, the groups of real $2 \times 2$ matrices of determinant $1$, acting on $\mathbb{C}\cup \infty$ by M¨obius transformations. 
For each of the points $0$, $i$, $−i$, compute its stabilizer and its orbit under the action of $G$. Show that $G$ has exactly $3$ orbits in all.

I have computed their stabilizer and orbits but not sure how to show $G$ only has exactly three orbits.
Greatly appreciated if anyone can help!

Comment: What did you get for the orbits?

Comment: for orb(0)=b/d where b,d belongs to R.

Comment: for orb(i)=(ai+b)/(ci+d)=(ac+bd+i)/(c^2+d^2);

Comment: for orb(-i)=(ac+bd-i)/(c^2+d^2) where a,b,c,d belongs to R

Comment: What are the possible values for Re(g(i)) and Im(g(i))?

Comment: Well, because a,b,c,d are arbitrary so I think Re(g(i)) and Im(g(i)) can be any value in R, but I can't prove them yet

Comment: Im(g(i)) is always positive.